# Hive Stages mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hive. I have few doubts.

1. I want to know how Hive transforms the queries to MapReduce jobs?
2. I have looked at the explain command which gives me a stage plan and
   dependencies. I want to know the details of stages. How these stages
   are defined?
3. How can I control the MapReduce execution. Suppose I want to change
   the Reduce join to a map side join.

Answer (score 4):

At an abstract level, the following things happen when you execute a query in hive

1. The query is parsed and a Abstract Syntax Tree is created
2. AST is then converted in to a DAG of MapReduce tasks
3. Then a Runnable is created for each of the MapReduce task.
4. The MapReduce tasks will be then serialized into xml file (stored at /tmp/hive-${user.name}/)
5. Execution engine will deserialize this xml file and execute the tasks

I hope this answers your questions 1 and 2. You can read more from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/nzhang/hive-anatomy)

For the question 3 i believe hive will automatically do a map-side join if possible. Check [HIVE-3784](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3784) 
Prior to which you have to give hint in hive query to do mapside join. See this [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3784)

To learn more about how joins work in hive see this [link](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/join-optimization-in-apache-hive/470667928919)